# Compiler Bigloo Issue

Tags: scheme, bigloo

The thing i want to ask, is what the difference, pressing the
"make an executable file" button in Dr.Racket, from making an executable file using bigloo.

Another question is, that im having problems to complile *.scm files, using bigloo.
Anyone can help me on this?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? I'm not too familiar with bigloo, but you shouldn't need to compile .scm files. You don't usually compile files in Scheme; you just send them through the REPL.

Comment: Bigloo is an ahead-of-time compiler for scheme, compiling to native code, .NET or Java class files. http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Manuel.Serrano/bigloo/doc/bigloo-3.html#Overview-of-Bigloo

Comment: well i need to use the command
"bigloo -o test test.scm" for example